# Django: List of valid field lookup operators

Tags: django, django-queryset

Does Django have an accessible list of all valid field lookup operators (those that are used by the QuerySet API, e.g. 'contains', 'in', 'lt', etc)?

Thanks

EDIT: For clarification, I mean an in-code list that I can import so, for example, I can check if a given string matches a valid operator.

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/ look in the django docs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Django 2.1, `django.db.models.sql.constants.QUERY_TERMS` constant is removed. Per the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#miscellaneous), Django recommends the `get_lookups()` method of the [Lookup Registration API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/lookups/#lookup-registration-api) as an alternative.

For a given field on a model, it can be accessed via:

```
MyModel._meta.get_field('my_field').get_lookups()
```

Answer (score 8):

After searching the source for the operators, it lives in `django.db.models.sql.constants.QUERY_TERMS`.

A dictionary with lookup strings mapped to `None`.

```
'exact' in QUERY_TERMS
```

Thanks for this! Never would have gone looking, but I could definitely use this.

Comment: As of Django 2.1, this answer is no longer valid. `QUERY_TERMS` is removed. See other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

they are in

```
your_model._meta.fields[index].class_lookups
```

It’s a dict.

Comment: This is indeed where they can be found as of Django 2.1, where the `QUERY_TERMS` constant is removed. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53717751/405174) for a possibly more stable API.